# Texto de "dica" do "código de conduta" precisa melhorar

Tags: bug, status-pronto, tradução

O texto ao passar o mouse sob a dica é mostrado algo como:

> Usuário é começou a colaborar agora com este site. Seja gentil ao pedir esclarecimentos, comentar, e responder. Consulte nosso Código de Conduta.
>
> [image: dica do código de conduta]

Já no editor aparece um texto mais simples e correto:

> Usuário é um usuário novo. Seja legal e dê uma olhada no nosso código de conduta

Além de ser menor, mas apresentando o que é necessário para quem for ler.

Sugiro usar o mesmo texto do editor nas dicas (tooltips)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Alterado para:

> $Owner$ é um usuário novo. Seja gentil ao pedir esclarecimentos, comentar, e responder.

https://pt.traducir.win/string/9206